# Latest Stable versions of cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, maven-3, cucumber-java

Could anyone please help me out with the latest versions of Cucumber Java. I am currently using 1.2.4 of Info.cukes and tried upgrading it with 6.1.1 of io.cucumber. getting intermittent issues.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently using cucumber-java version 5.7 and not having any problems. If you have issues with newer versions, please contact the community via the [support channels](https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/community/get-in-touch/).

There are also some breaking changes between major versions, so you might need to make some changes when upgrading. You can find links to some of the release notes in [this issue](https://github.com/cucumber/docs.cucumber.io/issues/142); the rest you should be able to find on the cucumber blog.

If you go through all of these and are still having problems, you may have found a bug. In that case, please also get in touch through the support channels.